# what are concept and specification files, they can create from file-> new in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, getgauge

I see two options named concept and specification in new in android studio.
what are these files and what are they do?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @CommonsWare 3.4

Comment: I do not see "Concept" and "Specification" options in the main menu (File > New) or the right-mouse context menu (New) in Android Studio 3.4.1. Perhaps you installed an add-on for Android Studio that added them.

Comment: @nicej can you provide picture ?

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe.. Thanks.

Comment: @Ashish I added picture

Comment: I also don't find any of these in my studio. have you added any plugins?  as per name this may related documentation.

Comment: @RajneeshShukla I have many plugins and I can't understand it related to which one. I also search .cpt (concept) file in android and didn't find any related to this.

Comment: then play with it with a demo program. You will get an idea :)

Comment: @RajneeshShukla Great comment but it has no document..I'll try..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have the [Gauge Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7535-gauge) for the [Gauge acceptance test framework](https://gauge.org/) installed in Android Studio. That the Specification and concepts appear in the kotlin section of the menu is the source of your confusion.

You can read more about using these specs [here](https://gauge.org/)